# Angular 5 - using the altmetric badge in the angular app gives uncaught Error: Template parse errors

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to use the `Altmetric Badge` inside my app according to their documentation in https://api.altmetric.com/embeds.html

In my component I included the script in this way (angular removes `<script tags>`), so this is an hack :

```
 @Input() doi;

    constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2,
                   @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document) {
    } 

    public ngOnInit() {
        const s = this.renderer2.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = 'https://d1bxh8uas1mnw7.cloudfront.net/assets/embed.js';
        this.renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, s);
    }
```

I am getting the `doi` as an input.

My `html` is :

```
 <div class="altmetric-embed" data-badge-type="donut" data-doi="{{doi}}"></div>
```

This does not work either :

```
<div class="altmetric-embed" data-badge-type="donut" [data-doi]="doi"></div>
```

But I am getting following error :

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'doi' since it
>   isn't a known property of 'div'.
>   ("etricCancel($event)">-->
>         ]data-doi="{{doi}}">

How can I make it work with my input?

Comment: Change ```data-doi="{{doi}}"``` to ```[attr.data-doi] = "doi"``` ...

Comment: Does not work either - compiler.js:2427 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'data-doi' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("etricCancel($event)"></exl-altmetric>-->
      <div class="altmetric-embed" data-badge-type="donut" [ERROR ->][data-doi]="doi"></div>

Comment: I have edited my comment already, use ```[attr.data-doi]``` ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `property binding` instead of `interpolation`

```
<div class="altmetric-embed" data-badge-type="donut" [attr.data-doi]="doi"></div>
```